# Im having an error trying to compile an nasm x86 assembly program that uses the c library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, nasm

Im trying to compile a nasm x86 assembly program that uses the c library. The code is

```
section .text
  global main
  extern printf

main:
  push msg
  mov eax, 0
  call printf

  add esp, 4

  ret


section .data
  msg db "Hello", 0xa, 0
```

Its a simple program that should print "Hello". Im trying to compile this with 2 commands

`nasm -f elf main.asm`
`gcc -m32 -o main main.o`

However, running `gcc -m32 -o main main.o` gives some errors.

The errors are:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 when searching for libgcc_s.so.1
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to install `gcc-multilib` because I heard that it helps but I kept getting the same error. Ive also tried updating gcc but that also did not help anything.

***EDIT:*** I fixed the errors! I had to install a 32 bit gcc library called `lib32-gcc-libs` and then it got fixed. However I still have 2 warnings.

```
main.o: warning: relocation in read-only section '.text'
warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
```

What do these warnings mean and how do I fix them?

Comment: It sounds like 32-bit libraries are not installed. What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I am using Arch Linux

Comment: "_I tried to install `gcc-multilib`_": Did you just try or did you install? Did you search for a tutorial, and what did you find, did it work?

Comment: I installs ``gcc-multilib``. I then tried to run the commands again, nothing changed

Comment: In order to install 32 bit libraries on arch linux do you enable multilib in ``pacman.conf``?

Comment: Try `call    printf@PLT`. Modern distros are security-conscious and don't allow hard-coding addresses, which is why you get a relocation now. Or something like that.

Comment: Undefined reference to ``printf@PLT`` When I compile it with gcc

Comment: [Understanding a DT\_TEXTREL warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651605) /  [Extern function declaration in Assembly produces a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68128327) re: the TEXTREL warning.