# Extern function declaration in Assembly produces a warning

Tags: c, assembly

I'm calling an extern function that was developed in assembly using the follow snippet of code:

```
extern int myfunction();
```

Apart from the execution code, to declare a function in assembly, I'm using:

```
.section .text
.global myfunction
.type myfunction, @function
```

This should tell the compiler that assembly file contains a reference of the external function called `myfunction`.
Then I compile the code, using the following commands:

```
gcc -m32 -o obj/main.o -c src/main.c
gcc -m32 -o obj/myfunction.o -c src/myfunction.s
gcc -o bin/myfunction obj/main.o obj/myfunction.o -m32
```

When I'm compiling using GCC 10, a warning is being shown:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: relocation in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
```

How can I suppress that warning?

Comment: How do you build the C source code? How do you build the assembler code? What flags are you passing to the compiler respective the assembler? Please [edit] your question to include a copy-paste the full and complete commands you use.

Comment: Next time please show your code so a better diagnosis can be given.  PIE is the most likely cause but without seeing your code, nobody can point out what part of your code causes this warning.

Comment: The warning is being generated at linking phase, pointing lines of function declaration.

Comment: @SerHack Are you sure?  Usually it should give you an address at which the problem occured.  If you assemble with `-g`, you might also get a line number.

Comment: Nope, it does not give a line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the flag `--no-pie` to your build commands. This specifies the compiler not to generate a PIE (Position Independent Executable) file. PIE is commonly used for shared libraries, so that the same library code can be loaded in a location in each program address space where it does not overlap with other memory in use (for example, other shared libraries).

Comment: Related: [Understanding a DT\_TEXTREL warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76651605) re: what the warning is about and what a TEXTREL is.

Comment: For me, `--no-pie` did not work because of the extra dash. Try `-no-pie` instead.